# Can I publish to multiple distinct etcd clusters from a single host?

Tags: cluster, etc

I have a number of distinct etcd clusters, I would like to be centrally controlled:

- I have **multiple distinct etcd clusters**. Hosts in one cluster should not have any access to config in another cluster.
- The **central hosts should be able to read and write to all clusters**, as this hosts role is to see and control all the clusters.

I'm not quite sure how to implement this.

- Can a single host running etcd be a member of multiple clusters?
- Does etcd allow me to to have a host that can communicate with multiple clusters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An etcd cluster is addressable by its host:port combination. So, it is possible to have a single host participating in multiple clusters at once; just as it is possible for a single host to be running several MySQL databases at one time.

As an example:

- central.example.com:4001 would talk to cluster1
- central.example.com:4002 would talk to cluster2

In the future we would like to add cluster addressing in the keyspace like Google Chubby has. This would look something like /keys/local/foobar /keys/remote.cluster/foobar. Although, the design and implementation of something like this hasn't been sorted out..

Also related to cluster sizing and communication are the forthcoming proxy and cluster management APIs which were recently discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreos-dev/qgz5DLl2h-E